# Chaining management commands from a Custom Django Command

Tags: python, django

I am doing some file aggregation / generation and want to immediately run collectstatic afterwards.  Ideally I either extend the collectstatic command (i don't know if this is possible) or I chain control to that command.  I have tried the second, which isnt working:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    can_import_settings = True

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        something_necessary()
        execute_from_command_line('collectstatic')
```

Many thanks in advance from this django newbie.

Edit running from the command line is interesting

```
C:\www\app>python manage.py customCmd
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Well OK - that is interesting, as my command doesn't use the MySQLdb.  But trying the collectstatic separately works:

```
C:\www\app>python manage.py collectstatic
C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\collectstatic.py:65: DeprecationWarning: stat_float_times() is deprecated
  os.stat_float_times(False)


You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?
```

If I write the command as simple as

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    can_import_settings = False

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        pass
```

I get the MySQLdb error from a command line run.

SO what I know

1. it works fine from PyCHarm IF i dont make the call to execute_from_command_line
2. I can't get my custom command to execute from the command line (python manage,py customCmd)
3. the collectstatic works fine from both the PyCHarm interface and the command line

Comment: In what way isn't  it working? Throwing an error? Executing but doing nothing?, ???

Comment: In pycharm it just kind of hangs, and I need to stop the command.   if I remove the last line it works fine.  I am trying to figure out the best way to run it separately from the console.

Comment: Hmmm by saying it hangs, I'm wondering if you're inadvertently getting stuck in an endless loop - perhaps with control flow or (more likely?) through imports. Django's a little touchy re: databases. I've got a website which doesn't use a DB and it was a lot of hassle to unpick it. Make sure that your `settings.py` has `DATABASES = {}` if you're not using a DB, otherwise django will try to load drivers anyway.

Comment: I do have a DB in my app (MySql) and that all works fine outside of this command.